# How to mimic the PHP ?? double question mark behaviour in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, php

```php
$client = [
  'info' => [
    'company' => 'Apple',
  ]
];

echo $client['information']['company'] ?? 'N/A';
```

The above PHP code will show `N/A` as output, quietly. While the following Javascript will throw a `Uncaught TypeError`:

```js
var user = JSON.parse(' { "info" : { "company" : "apple" } } ');

console.log(user.information.company ?? 'N/A');
```

Is there a similar `??` operation in Javascript which can show the `N/A` result quietly?

Comment: You could use [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) with null coalescing which has a similar behaviour e.g. you'd do `user?.information?.company ?? 'N/A'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Javascript `??` refer to [Nullish coalescing operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator) That returns its right-hand side operand when its left-hand side operand is null or undefined.

`user.information.company` will return *Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'company' of undefined* Error instead.

Better to use **The optional chaining operator (?.)** in this case, that permits reading the value of a property located deep within a chain of connected objects without having to expressly validate that each reference in the chain is valid.

**Sample :**

```js
var user = JSON.parse(' { "info" : { "company" : "apple" } } ');
console.log(user?.information?.company ?? 'N/A');
```